# QGIS - How can I get the name of the source algorithm in a model script?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, model

I'm trying to write a simple model script that accepts the result of a JOIN algorithm and I need to get the name of the source algorithm that feeds my script.

My goal is to create a summary of multiple memory layers resulting from joins. I want to create table that lists the algorithm name and number of feature results.

I need the skeleton code to get the name of the algorithm that is feeding my script.

[image]